# Copying text from the Anaconda Prompt on Windows

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-lab

How can you copy text from the Anaconda Prompt on Windows? Naturally I would try to highlight the text and copy but on Anaconda Prompt (at least on Windows) you can not highlight text.